# T-SQL - Parse Item Child is XML in Table

Tags: xml, t-sql, parsing

I have this table

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE 
             (
                [ItemId] NVARCHAR(250),
                [Quantity] DECIMAL(18, 2),
                xmlData XML
             );

INSERT INTO @tbl 
VALUES ('Item1', 3, '<record>  <memberList>    <itemMember>      <quantity>3.0</quantity>      <item internalId="553">             </item>         </itemMember>    <itemMember>      <quantity>2.0</quantity>      <item internalId="554">         </item>       </itemMember> </memberList></record>'),
       ('Item2', 5, '<record>  <memberList>    <itemMember>      <quantity>4.0</quantity>      <item internalId="53">           </item>        </itemMember>    <itemMember>      <quantity>6.0</quantity>      <item internalId="54">             </item>         </itemMember>    </memberList></record>')
```

I try to parse the XML to get Item Child in table.

My expected result:

```
DECLARE @Result TABLE 
                (
                    [ItemId] NVARCHAR(250),
                    [Quantity] DECIMAL(18, 2),
                    [ItemChild] NVARCHAR(250),
                    [QtyChild] NVARCHAR(250)
                );

INSERT INTO @tbl 
VALUES ('Item1', 3, '553', 3), ('Item1', 3, '554', 2),
       ('Item2', 5, '53', 4), ('Item2', 5, '54', 6)
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO @Result(ItemId, Quantity, ItemChild, QtyChild)
    SELECT
        t.ItemId,
        t.Quantity,
        xc.value('(item/@internalId)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(250)'),
        xc.value('(quantity)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(250)')
    FROM
        @tbl t
    CROSS APPLY
        t.xmlData.nodes('/record/memberList/itemMember') AS XT(XC)
```

But I'd also *recommend* using the **most appropriate** data types for your columns `ItemChild` and `QtyChild` - those **are** numeric, so you should really not store them as `NVARCHAR(250)` - use `INT` for `ItemChild`, and `DECIMAL(18,2)` for `QtyChild` instead!

```
DECLARE @Result TABLE 
                (
                    [ItemId] NVARCHAR(250),
                    [Quantity] DECIMAL(18, 2),
                    [ItemChild] INT,
                    [QtyChild] DECIMAL(18, 2)
                );

INSERT INTO @Result(ItemId, Quantity, ItemChild, QtyChild)
    SELECT
        t.ItemId,
        t.Quantity,
        xc.value('(item/@internalId)[1]', 'INT'),
        xc.value('(quantity)[1]', 'DECIMAL(18, 2)')
    FROM
        @tbl t
    CROSS APPLY
        t.xmlData.nodes('/record/memberList/itemMember') AS XT(XC)
```

Comment: oh Yeah, Thanks for your help. I will do like it.